# Object in loop won't cast shadow over whole lopop with Three.js

Tags: javascript, loops, three.js, shadow, light

Why is not every cube in my loop casting a shadow?

I work with a directional light all of the cubes should cast shadows. But for some reason, it stops after 5 or so columns.

```
let dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1.5);
dirLight.position.set(300, -300, 400);
dirLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(dirLight);

dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;
dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512;
dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

let cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 3, 1);
let cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xf54242
});

function drawCubes() {
    for (let c = 0; c < 25; c++) {
        for (let r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
            for (let t = 0; t < 2; t++) {
                let cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
                cube.position.x = c * 1.3;
                cube.position.y = r * 3.02;
                cube.position.z = t * 1.01;
                cube.castShadow = true;
                cube.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add(cube);
            }
        }
    }

}
drawCubes();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shadows are clipped since the default frustum of the directional shadow camera is too small. Try it like so:

```js
const d = 50;

dirLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;
```

You can also use `THREE.CameraHelper` in order to debug the shadow camera. Very helpful for adjustments. Keep in mind that the shadow quality highly depends on the frustum. Tighter frustums produce sharper shadows.

```js
scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( dirLight.shadow.camera ) );
```

`three.js R109`

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.